# Google Distance Matrix returning wrong location based on Zip Code

Tags: google-distancematrix-api

I'm sending the following to get the distance between two zip codes via MS Access.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=74104&destinations=30333&units=imperial&key=******
```

The response however is giving me the wrong location:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
<status>OK</status>
<origin_address>74210 Doussard, France</origin_address>
<destination_address>Atlanta, GA 30333, USA</destination_address>
<row>
<element>
<status>ZERO_RESULTS</status>
</element>
</row>
</DistanceMatrixResponse>
```

It continually mixes up 74104 (Tulsa, OK) with 74210 (Doussard, France)

What could be causing that?